# How to install "fbi-master" R-package? Not visible in RStudio library

Tags: r, rtools

I want to install these R pakage in R-Studios.

https://github.com/cykbennie/fbi

How can I install it?

I installed Rtools and set up the path.

> Sys.which("make")
> "C:\rtools40\usr\bin\make.exe"

And afterwards I installed "fbi-master".

> install.packages("C:/Users/user/Downloads/fbi-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
> Installiere Paket nach ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
> (da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)

After this, the pakage is in the right folder "win-library/4.1" how all my other packages. But unfortunately it is not visible in R-Studios library.

> library(fbi-master)
> Error in library(fbi - master) : 'package' must be of length 1.

What I must do to install the package and and use its functions?

Thank you for any ideas an help.

Best regards.

Comment: The package name is `fbi`, not `fbi-master`.

Comment: I have Version R x64 4.1.3. But which version do I need for installing? In saw in the fbi.pdf: Depends R>3.5. Thank you for helping.

Comment: You need a version of 3.5 or more, as it says. I'd follow the instructions on https://github.com/cykbennie/fbi to install, don't try installing a binary zip file.

Comment: Now it works. I installed all requirements: install.packages("stats"), install.packages("readr"), install.packages("pracma"). And after this, it was possible to install "fbi" via: devtools::install_github("cykbennie/fbi"). Thank you for helping.

Comment: For future reference:  none of the earlier `install.packages` were really necessary.  `devtools::install_github` does those automatically.